# Construct matrix given eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$, how do I construct a matrix whose eigenvectors and eigenvalues are $v$ and $\lambda$?

The straightforward way of doing this is to encapsulate all $n^2$ constraints into a linear system and solve for each element of the matrix $M_i$. I.e.,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{11} & v_{12} & \dots & v_{1n} & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & v_{11} & v_{12} & \dots & v_{1n} & \dots & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0\\
 & & & & &  & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & \dots & v_{n1} & v_{n2} & \dots & v_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
M_1 \\ M_2 \\ \vdots \\ M_{n^2}
\end{bmatrix}

= 

\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 v_{11} \\ \lambda_1 v_{12} \\ \vdots \\\lambda_n v_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: In the basis consisting of the eigenvectors, the matrix would be diagonal, with the $\lambda_i$ as diagonal values, call it $D$. Next you write down the matrix whose columns are the coordinates of the $v_i$, call it $P$, and the matrix you are looking for is $P^{-1}DP$.

Comment: This is pretty standard - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix

Comment: @anon: Of course. I should've seen that

Comment: @Jacob: you have asked us to delete this question, but it even has an answer you accepted! It is generally not a good idea to delete a question which would imply deleting the work contributed by others.

Comment: @Mariano: Agreed. I accepted it because it was correct, but wanted it deleted because it seemed trivial on afterthought and I realized I should've thought about it a bit more.

Comment: @Jacob: it is *always* the case that one should have thought about everything better, and with time (hopefully) everything becomes —if not entirely trivial— at least easier.

Comment: @Mariano: Quite true :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your system of equations is $Mv_1=\lambda_1v_1,\ldots,Mv_n=\lambda_nv_n$. Or equivalently, $M(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=(\lambda_1 v_1,\ldots,\lambda_n v_n)$, where $V:=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is the $n\times n$-matrix with columns $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. You can write this as $MV=VD$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. So, assuming $V$ is invertible, that is, that your given eigenvectors are linearly independent, you get $M=VDV^{-1}$. Thus to calculate $M$ this way, all you need to do is to find the inverse of the matrix of eigenvectors, and multiply three matrices together.

Comment: Also, if you've been given *orthonormal* eigenvectors, computing $V^{-1}$ is particularly simple...

Comment: Is there an efficient way to do this without computing $V^{-1}$? I mean, computing $V^{-1}$ cost too much when Matrix V is huge.

Comment: @CLei if the eigenvectors constructing $V$ are orthonormal as Nate stated, $V^{-1} = V^t$