# Could we determine entries of a matrix which has repeating eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a involutive 3x3 matrix whose eigenvalue set is $-1$ repeated three times , and I also know it's only eigen vector is $n$. Is it possibly to figure out the matrix entries?

If the matrix is $A$, so far I know it must be satisfy the following eqtns:

1. Trace(A)=-3
2. det(A)=-1
3. $A^2=I$

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119668/determine-a-matrix-knowing-its-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors)

Comment: what does the letter $n$  mean?

Comment: Oh, I mean a vector $n$ @WillJagy

Comment: My matrix has only one eigen vector, the one you said has many @angryavian

Answer (score 1):

If $-1$ is the only eigenvalue and if its eigenspace is one-dimensional (I assume this is what you mean by "it has only one eigenvector," since $cn$ is also an eigenvector for any nonzero scalar $c$), then $A$ must be similar to
$$J := \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ & -1 & 1\\&&-1\end{bmatrix},$$
i.e. $A=PJP^{-1}$ for some $P$ whose first column is $n$.

However, it is impossible for $A^2=I$ because $J^2 \ne I$. So I don't think there exists a matrix with your conditions.